# URL too long for adding WFS? How to make a shortcut?

Tags: qgis, wfs, url

I'm trying to get a public WFS into my QGIS Desktop (2.18.13) on Windows, so I tried adding an ArcGIS-FeatureServer-Layer and get the prompt:

> Couldn't load service properties: :

I noticed, that QGIS is cutting off the URL I'm trying to use:

http://geodienste-umwelt.hessen.de/arcgis/services/inspire/gewaessernetz/MapServer/WFSServer?&request=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.0&SERVICE=WFS

is cut off to:

http://geodienste-umwelt.hessen.de/arcgis/services/inspire/gewaessernetz/MapServer/WFSServer?VERSION=1.1.0&

If I paste the URL in my Browser, it seems okay, but:

1. Is QGIS really cutting off URLs?
2. Is there a way to shorten the URL? (I'm thinking of my Windows Host file or a similar solution)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with length, QGIS is just removing parameters that it intends to add it's self

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add it as a standard **WFS layer** instead of as an ArcGIS MapServer Layer (I'm guessing `&SERVICE=WFS` is cut out as you're already selecting to load it as a WFS layer):

```
Layer > Add Layer > Add WFS Layer...
```

[image: WFS layer]

---

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a URL shortener such as google's.
https://goo.gl/

Comment: This could cause problems with the service calls though, because QGIS will add the necessary request parameters for the operations it needs to do to get more information, or the data. You'll get conflicting request parameters, a request like `...request=GetCapabilities&request=GetFeature&...`